# Deleting one div box affects the other div box, even though they are not related in any way

Tags: css, html, spacing

I am trying to delete the white box on this website (http://www.tokensofchange.org/) below the "features"  section. The div itself is extremely simple:

```
<div class="donatenew"></div>
```

and the css:

```
.donatenew {
  width:100%;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  height:1000px;
  }
```

But whenever I delete the "donatenew" div, the div below, the "bottomnew" div gets messed up, meaning it essentially deletes itself leaving just the text.

The html for the bottomnew div:

```
<div class="bottomnew">

<a href="http://www.beaurosariophoto.com">Beau R.</a> | (Photo)
<a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/jb-london">JB-London</a> | (Photo)
<a href="#"></a> | (Logo)

</div class="bottomnew">
```

and the css:

```
.bottomnew {
  width:100%;
  background: #d1d1d1;
  height: 300px;
  border-top: 6px solid #a9a9a9;
}

.bottomnew:a:link {color:#0088cc;
                   text-decoration: none;
                   }
           a:visited {}
           a:hover {color:#005580;}
           a:active {} 
 }
```

Does anyone know why the "bottomnew" div becomes messed up whenever the "donatenew" div is deleted from the html? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You want the white box at the footer area removed? I tried deleting donatenew div in the inspector and it leaves the footer with your text, around 5px height, is that not fine?

Comment: Remove that empty paragraph and try to wrap your sections correctly (like <div id="content-12"> etc)

Comment: Ali Gajani, I am trying to keep the footer at 180 px in height, but when the donatenew div is deleted, the footer changes from 180 px to 5 px.

Comment: I know what the problem is, check out my answer below. You have extra closing div tags.

Answer (score 0):

This might not solve the problem entirely but I know it will put you in the right direction. I inspected your source code and you have 48 opening `<div>` tags and 55 closing `</div>` tags. That's the problem. You should use [this](http://www.tormus.com/tools/div_checker) tool to check your DIV map.

The tool reports that you have 7 extra closing div tags, as I already said before. Once you click the div map link on that tool, you can figure out  (highlighted in yellow) the extra closing `div` tags. Here's a sample of this.

[image]

[image]

> Do you see where the problem is ? I am sure you do. Reinspect your
>   markup.

Comment: I fixed all of the extra closing divs but the problem still persists.

Comment: Can we please see the updated live link of your page?